# Microsoft Graph get sharepoint sites analytics not working

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I tried to query the analytics of a SharePoint site using Microsoft Graph from Microsoft Flow. Before I do this, I tried this in Graph Explorer.

The following url is used.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxx.sharepoint.com,xxxx,xxxx/analytics
```

This error message is displayed.

> We had an issue sending this request to the Graph API. For assistance, connect with us on StackOverflow with the tag [microsoftgraph].

I have no problem with these two queries:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxx.sharepoint.com,xxxx,xxxx

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxx.sharepoint.com,xxxx,xxxx/lists
```

It just doesn't work with analytics.

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/itemanalytics-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs), Analytics is not available in all national deployments but I'm in global tenant so I assume it is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a "lastSevenDays" or "allTime" specifier at the end of the url may help you out

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxx.sharepoint.com,xxxx,xxxx/analytics/lastSevenDays
```

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxx.sharepoint.com,xxxx,xxxx/analytics/allTime
```